# Use curl to PUT or DELETE http queries in apache web server

Tags: apache, http, put, http-method

I am trying a very basic experiment , and not sure where I am going wrong.

My task is to try out HTTP queries like PUT, GET , DELETE , POST with the help of CURL command on my linux box.

On apache server i have

```
httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Feb 22 2013 12:01:55
```

I am using basic apache service ( do not intend to use PHP or CGI for this purpose).

I am able to do

```
curl  -X GET http://example.com/test/test1
curl  http://example.com/test/
```

BUT not able to do

1. PUT/POST ,( I do see a log entry in access_log , but nothing happens)

   curl -T 1.1 http://example.com/test/


   405 Method Not Allowed

   ## Method Not Allowed

   The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL /test/1.1.

   ---

   Apache/2.2.15  Port 80
2. Nor even delete.

   curl -X DELETE http://example.com/test/1


   405 Method Not Allowed

   ## Method Not Allowed

   The requested method DELETE is not allowed for the URL /test/1.

   ---

   Apache/2.2.15  Port 80

I have tried adding below part in httpd.conf

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    <Limit GET HEAD POST PUT DELETE OPTIONS>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Limit>
</Directory>
```

but this didn't help. (Tried /var/www/html as directory too)
Does anyone have any clue why it is not working for me ?

Note:- Just to make this clear, I am using basic http configuration , no fancy stuff. Just want to try these HTTP queries and see how it goes.